# Starting from which version does Gradle support Java 21?

Tags: java, gradle, java-21

When trying to configure the project using Java 21 I'm getting the error:

> Unsupported Java. Your build is currently configured to use Java 21 and Gradle 8.3.

Unfortunately, there is no information in official documentation for now: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

> A Java version between 8 and 20 is required to execute Gradle. Java 21
> and later versions are not yet supported.

Starting from which version does Gradle support Java 21?

Comment: Current Gradle does not support current Java. That seems to be usual, Gradle tends to lag behind current technologies.

Comment: You can watch https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/25574 for the news.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't feel like a question that should have been closed (in general, and specifically as seeking recommendations for tools, etc.).  It has a current concrete answer (it's not yet supported, but will be with [gradle#25574](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/25574)).  As well as the related answer that you should still be able to build a Java 21 project with Gradle running under an earlier version of Java using tool `java { toolchain { languageVersion = 21 } }`

Comment: @M.Justin The question is already answered by the quote from the OP: there is currently no version which supports Java 21. There is no real question, so the close is valid. And asking what future version will support Java 21 will either solicit opinion/guesses, or is a request for external resources (e.g. a roadmap).

Comment: If you are using Kotlin, then you can change Kotlin version to 1.9.20-Beta2, It's fixed my problem

Comment: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.3 --distribution-type bin` fixed weird warnings in intellij and weird test fails on the command line for me. My previous gradle version was 8.2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Current

For full Java 21 support, you can use [Gradle 8.5](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases). The [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html#full-java-21-support) say:

> With this release, Gradle now fully supports compiling, testing and running on Java 21.

Comment: I do like that the release notes call out _why_ Java 21 is not yet supported: "Currently, you cannot run Gradle on Java 21 because Kotlin lacks support for JDK 21. However, support for running Gradle with Java 21 is expected in future versions."

Comment: @MJustin to add to that: 1.9.20 (currently preview, scheduled for release ca. Dec 2023) Kotlin releases are already compatible with JVM 21, so I guess that early 2024 is the actual expected date here for Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in other answers, Gradle 8.4 supports building Java 21 projects.

As to *how* to do that:

1. Install JDK21 on the machine and tell Gradle to use it as its toolchain.
   In your Gradle build file (build.gradle or build.gradle.kts):

   ```
   java {
       toolchain {
           languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
       }
   }
   ```

   Gradle should find your JDK21 installation [automatically](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection).
2. Install a JDK version *below 21* and use it to execute your Gradle tasks:
   Either point your JAVA_HOME variable to this lower version JDK installation, or point the property `org.gradle.java.home` (gradle.properties) to it. If you use IntelliJ, you should instead point the setting 'Gradle JVM' to this JDK.

To upgrade Gradle to 8.4, either download it from [gradle.org](https://gradle.org/next-steps/?version=8.4&format=bin) and install it manually or (preferably) update your gradle-wrapper.properties file with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip`.

Explanation: by default, Gradle uses the same JDK that it runs on to compile your sources. Obviously that is not going to work when you need to compile Java 21 code but the latest Gradle release doesn't run on Java 21 yet.
So you let Gradle run on a lower version (either your environment default - what is returned by *java --version*, or some other JDK as specified for instance in the *Gradle JVM* option of IntelliJ or by setting org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties) but you instruct it to use a 21 JDK for building your project (compilation, javadoc generation, etc.).

`Edit`: Despite [claims](https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/release-notes.html#support-for-building-projects-with-java-21) to the contrary by Gradle, it seems that (at least for simple projects) Gradle 8.4 is already able to run on Java 21.
If you run into problems use the steps above, but it should be enough to simply run `gradle build`/`gradlew build` with JDK21 and Gradle 8.4 (so step 2 can be skipped).
Starting with Gradle 8.5 it should be officially supported to run Gradle directly on JDK21.

Answer (score 4):

Current **Gradle Version 8.4** allows you to **build** with Java 21. Gradle 8.4 itself however can't run on Java 21. The next **Version 8.5**, where you can already try the RC-4 release, will be able to **run on Java 21**.

https://docs.gradle.org/8.5-rc-3/release-notes.html#full-java-21-support

---

**Java 22:**

**Gradle 8.7 can build** for Java 22, but **needs Java 21** or older **to run**.

Comment: what AGP version supported for that ?

Comment: isn't java backwards compatible?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is new release of gradle for JDK 21:

https://docs.gradle.org/8.4-rc-1/release-notes.html#kotlin-dsl-improvements

gradle 8.4-rc-1

I was able to install, but I'm still having java errors with classpath issues.

Comment: Have you tried a snapshot of Gradle 8.5?

Comment: FWIW: I'm running 8.5-rc-3 successfully.

Answer (score 3):

[Gradle 8.5 is now GA](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html) and it has **full** Java 21 support.

You can update your wrapper config file to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
```

And if you are using idea, you can go `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle` and change the Gradle JVM to 21.

[image: gradle jvm 21]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intellij, until v8.5 is G.A, you need to set Gradle JVM to a JVM version lower than Java 21, example Java 20:

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle:

[image]

Comment: It's quite a shame that Gradle is taking this long to support JDK 21

Comment: 8.5 is now available