# Upgraded a Java project from version 12 to 21 (using Gradle 8.4) and getting Unsupported class file major version 65

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradlew

Running:

```
gradlew build --scan
```

gives:

```
Unsupported class file major version 65
```

I've read similar problems (version < 65) and solutions. What's going on?!

I installed JDK 21 and set JAVA_HOME.

```
java -version

java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

gradle-wrapper.properties uses 8.4:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I also tried Gradle 8.5 - same error.

which is compatible according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

In IntelliJ 2023.3:

```
File, Settings
Build, Execution, Deployment
Build Tools, Gradle
Gradle JVM: JAVA_HOME Oracle Open JDK version 21.0.1
Build and run using: Gradle
Run tests using: Gradle
Gradle distribution: Wrapper
```

gradlew -version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64
```

```
Compiler, Java Compiler
Use compiler: Javac
Project bytecode version: 21

File, Project Structure 
Project Settings, Project
SDK: 21 Oracle Open JDK version 21.0.1
Language level: 21
Modules Main and Test use Module SDK: 21 Oracle Open JDK version 21.0.1

Platform Settings, SDKs
21, JDK Home Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
```

Using Gradle 8.5 gave the same error.

Why am I getting:

```
Unsupported class file major version 65
```

Stacktrace snippet (SO won't allow me to embed images and I can't provide a link:

```
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.createClassDescriptor(MainClassFinder.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.doWithMainClasses(MainClassFinder.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.findSingleMainClass(MainClassFinder.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.ResolveMainClassName.findMainClass(ResolveMainClassName.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.ResolveMainClassName.resolveMainClassName(ResolveMainClassName.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.ResolveMainClassName.resolveAndStoreMainClassName(ResolveMainClassName.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
```

I upgraded springBootVersion from "2.0.6.RELEASE" to "2.7.0".

Before JDK upgrade:

```
springBootVersion = "2.0.6.RELEASE"
```

Now:

```
springBootVersion = "2.7.0"
```

Plugins:

```
plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.2.1"
    id "com.github.spotbugs" version "4.5.0"
    id 'pmd'
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "no.nils.wsdl2java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlVersion}")
        classpath("no.nils:wsdl2java:${wsdl2javaVersion}")
    }
```

Comment: By the way, for Java 21 you [should be using Gradle 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77179202/642706).

Comment: I tried Gradle 8.5 - same error.

Comment: Too little information **when** do you get this error.Please provide more/full output of the build.

Comment: The _"Unsupported class file major version 65"_ can also be produced by tools like byte-code enhancers. You need to provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace, not just the exception message.

Comment: Use the `--stacktrace` flag with gradle to get the precise location where the problem occurs. Odds are that *some plugin* is trying to parse class files (likely with the ASM library or something similar) and **that** can't handle class file major version 65. That means it's not actually an old JDK, but an old library. And the stacktrace will help you figure out where that's used (i.e. which plugin might need an upgrade).

Comment: I've added a stacktrace snippet. I can't post the full trace as SO won't allow me to embed images and I can't provide a link. I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0

Comment: ["Spring Boot 2.7.0 requires Java 8 and is compatible up to and including Java 18."](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements). You need to upgrade to a later version of spring boot. 3.2.0 supports Java 21.

Comment: I've added plugins and dependencies. Plugin: plugin: "org.springframework.boot". Dependency: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}". I'll try Spring Boot 3.2.0.

Comment: You might get lucky if you use a higher 2.7.x version (current latest 2.7.x is 2.7.18, I'm not sure why you're 18 point releases behind...), as it might use a newer version of ASM, but given that is not formally supported, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: In addition to upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2, you will also need to make some code changes to migrate to the new version properly. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-3-migration for a guide.

Comment: I've abandoned migrating to Java 21 and am instead migrating to 17.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the information that @BasilBourque gave in comments of question.

You have to switch to version 8.5 of Gradle according to [Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) because Gradle 8.4 supported compiling and testing with Java 21 using Java toolchains, but running Gradle itself on Java 21 was not yet supported.

More details about it you have to check [Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html#full-java-21-support) of Gradle 8.5.

Comment: I tried Gradle 8.5 - same error.

Comment: add full stack trace as update of question because I suspect that the problem is not in jdk version

Comment: I've added a stacktrace snippet. I can't post the full trace as SO won't allow me to embed images and I can't provide a link. I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0

Comment: I've added plugins and dependencies. Plugin: plugin: "org.springframework.boot". Dependency: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}". I'll try Spring Boot 3.2.0.

Comment: Yes, I have just read the comments of the question and yes it also could cause the problem, let me know it in `spring-boot` version was the problem.

Comment: I've abandoned migrating to Java 21 and am instead migrating to 17.